# Convert date in one timezone to another timezone using timezone abbreviations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web application where a user can set his/her timezone in the application which is further used in the application for various date-time conversions. The selected timezone can be different from user's locale timezone.

I am currently stuck on a problem where I need to compare a user selected date(which user assumes to be in the timezone selected by him/her in the application) with the current date to see if the selected date is a date in future. With reference to all the places I have searched, I have found that I can get current date in user locale or UTC time.

So the gist of my problem is - Is there any way to convert a date from one timezone to another using the timezone abbreviations?

I have searched a lot before posting here but could not get any solution. Most of the places that I found during my search suggest that there is no such solution available.

I have tried using date.js but it does not suffice the purpose as it is quite outdated and also the timezone abbreviations supported by it is a very limited set. I have also taken a look a timezoneJS but I don't think that it works with timezone abbreviations.

Is there any way in which it can be accomplished using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// calculate local time in a different city given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    var date = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset 
    // get UTC time in msec
    var utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    var newDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + newDate.toLocaleString();
}

// get Bombay time
console.log(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5'));

// get Singapore time
console.log(calcTime('Singapore', '+8'));

// get London time
console.log(calcTime('London', '+1'));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... it works for all the timezones where day light saving is not active. Please tell me, how to get it working for timezones with daylight saving?

Comment: Yes. It is not a built in Jscript fuction. Its a calculated conversion.

Comment: If you are using timezone-js then this is the code:

var dt = new timezoneJS.Date("2012/04/10 10:10:30 +0000", 'Europe/London');
dt.setTimezone("Asia/Jakarta");

console.debug(dt); //return formatted date-time in asia/jakarta

Comment: Yeah I got that its a calculated conversion but is there a way to determine that daylight saving should be on for current time? No I am not using timezoneJS, it does not suit my needs.